# Paste clipboard content without X

Tags: ssh, arch-linux, clipboard

I'm sshing into ArchLinux machine from Ubuntu. I want to be able to copy some text from Ubuntu and paste it into a file in Archlinux from terminal. xclip doesn't work for me, because I'm unable to set up X. Any suggestions?

Ideally what I want to be able to do is what I do under Ubuntu:

```
xclip -o > file.txt
```

Except without using xclip

Comment: Doesn't merely your Ubuntu terminal support copy/paste? How are you ssh'ing ?

Comment: @tonioc ssh user@host

Comment: sorry my question was maybe not clear enough: are you ssh'ing from Ubuntu graphical desktop? If so, the native copy/paste should be enough (it is for me in similar environments).

Comment: You need to pass the `-X` (or `-Y` see the man page) option to `ssh` for `ssh` to forward the X11 connections so `xclip` on Arch can connect to your X11 display on Ubuntu and query the content of the selection there.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yes, but the question us how to avoid using xclip

Comment: @tonioc That's what I'm doing anyways, but I would prefer if I could use something like xclip

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use `scp` that is used to transfer files ?

To log the command output (with errors):

```
command >> log 2>&1
```

And to get the log to your machine (execute it outside of `ssh`):

```
scp user@server:/path/to/log
```

I hope it will help.